# What benefit is there to playing highly repetitive games?

Tags: video-games

I quite enjoy playing games which requires many repetitions of the level in order to get right. These games are often constant-speed scrolling obstacle-course type games where the player must navigate obstacles correctly to finish the level. Often many of repetitions of the level are necessary. For example, [geometry dash](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cIaXQwHUJQ4) (not affiliated with them at all, I promise!).

I often wonder if there are any benefits to playing these games. I know that the repetitive nature creates neural pathways in the brain, but I don't think this newly developed ability is going to be used outside of one game in particular.

A friend of mine mentioned that perhaps these games would improve neuroplasticity, and some research indicates that certain types of games do have cognitive health benefits, (for example, [in older adults](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4196565/#!po=7.00000)). However, I haven't been able to find any information about this type of game in particular.

Do these types of repetitive games have any neurological benefit outside of an improved ability to play a particular game?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lumosity has a [research section](http://www.lumosity.com/hcp) that explains how their repetitive games help in day-to-day activities. They claim it's peer reviewed, although all of the papers are published to their site.

However, [Science based medicine](https://www.sciencebasedmedicine.org/brain-training-products-useless-in-study/) had this to say about a study with games similar to Lumosity...

> This one study, of course, is not definitive. It is possible that more training is needed before significant benefits are seen. Perhaps
>   video games are more effective because they are more engaging and
>   players will spend more time playing.What this study shows, however,
>   is that products sold as brain training games had no documented
>   benefits after six weeks of use.
>
> Putting this study into the context of the overall research, it does
>   make us more cautious about concluding that there are general
>   cognitive benefits to brain training games or entertainment video
>   games. Benefits are likely to be closely related to the specific tasks
>   involved in training, and not transfer to unrelated tasks.
>
> But there is already enough published evidence showing visual
>   tracking, multitasking, and executive function benefits from action
>   and strategic video games respectively that this study will not be the
>   final word. When there is conflicting research, more study is needed.
>
> This study is most applicable to brain training products, and shows
>   that the marketing claims for these products are not justified. There
>   is very unlikely to be any benefit, or any specific advantage, to
>   “scientifically designed” brain training applications. For now, you
>   are better off just playing a video game.

So, more or less, there isn't any information suggesting that these repetitive "brain games" actually help develop skills outside of learning to play the game better.

Comment: Thanks for your first answer at Cognitive Sciences! Could you perhaps conclude this answer with a short wrap-up of the rather long quote? As of now it seems basically a copy-pasted answer.

Comment: @AliceD updated